# Permissions on phone while debugging?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

I'm implementing a backup method to copy the app database to the SDCard.

This works fine in the emulator, but when I try to run it on my phone it crashes.  Following is the relevant stacktrace:

```
W/KeyCharacterMap(15814): Can't open keycharmap file
W/KeyCharacterMap(15814): Error loading keycharmap file '/data/usr/keychars/tegra-kbc.kcm.bin'.     hw.keyboards.0.devname='tegra-kbc'
W/System.err(15814): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/GroceryList.bak (Permission denied)
W/System.err(15814):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
W/System.err(15814):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
W/System.err(15814):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
W/System.err(15814):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:66)
```

My first thought was permissions (due to the permission denied in the stacktrace), but I double checked my manifest and it **does** contain:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In case it's something in the method:

```
public void backup() {
    try {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File outputFile = new File(sdcard,
                "GroceryList.bak");
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File inputFile = new File(data,
                "data/cdc.workshopapps.grocerylist/databases/GroceryList");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Error("Copying Failed");
    }
}
```

Is there something I need to do to enable that permission on the phone other than Run the program from Eclipse?

**EDIT**

Entire manifest as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cdc.workshopapps.grocerylist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".GroceryListMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And in case it matters, the phone I'm using is a Motorola Droid X2 (it mattered on my last issue, so I thought I'd mention it).

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException - That is your problem

Comment: Umm, of course it isn't... I'm trying to create it there.  :p

Comment: My bad, quick look didn't see (Permission denied)

Comment: Google said the SD card shouldn't be mounted and uses-permission has to be outside the <application> tag

Comment: That's it.  I couldn't do it while the USB was jacked in.  Please post this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. Always use google first.

Comment: I tried... apparently my google-fu is weak today.  Out of curosity, what was your search?

Comment: sd card android permission denied - scanned the first 3 links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment "Google said the SD card shouldn't be mounted." was the correct answer according to OP.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the file doesn't exist...
Try creating it first:

```
 File outputFile = new File(sdcard, "GroceryList.bak");
 if (!outputFile.exists())
     outputFile.createNewFile();
```

Comment: I'll give it a try... since I was following another answer here, I didn't think I'd have to add anything extra to it.

Comment: Didn't work, changed the error though:  `W/System.err(17105): java.io.IOException: Permission denied`  I keep coming back to permissions, but I have the required permission in my manifest...

Comment: Paste your AndroidManifest.xml. The problem might be the place you've put your permission

Comment: As user1378730 said, try moving your permission statement outside of the application tag.

Comment: I think the file not existing might have been part of it as well, so +1, although the ultimate answer was removing the USB cable.

Comment: You don't have to remove the USB cable. Just make sure you're plugging it in a different mode than "USB Storage".
Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this file already exists? sometimes just creating the file object (new File(..)) does not create the file itself. If FileNotFoundException is occurring means, then file just doesn't exist yet. You can create it by calling file.createNewFile().

```
 File f= new File(sdcard, "GroceryList.bak");
   if(!f.exists())
   f.createNewFile();
```